# Javascript: How to draw two rectangles that can be controlled by buttons

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, graphics

I am sorry if this is a stupid question. I am new to Javascript.
I want to draw two rectangles that can be controlled by a few buttons. 
I am able to implement one rectangle and it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/6vxd03qq/ 
But, I am not sure why code for implementing two rectangles is not working: http://jsfiddle.net/yhhk9meg/ 
Is it possible to use class to do that? If yes how?

**Code:**

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title>test</title>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="moveRight"><==</button>
<button id="moveLeft">==></button>
<button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
<button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
<button id="filled">Filled</button>
<button id="empty">Empty</button>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

var object = {
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        x: 100,
        y: 50, 
        filled: false       
}


    document.getElementById("moveRight").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.x -= 10;
    });
    document.getElementById("moveLeft").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.x += 10;
    });
    document.getElementById("bigger").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.height += 10;
        object.width += 10;
    });
    document.getElementById("smaller").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.height -= 10;
        object.width -= 10;
    });
    document.getElementById("filled").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.filled = true;
    });
    document.getElementById("empty").addEventListener("click", function(){
        object.filled = false;
    });



    function renderCanvas(){
        ctx.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
        ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function renderObject(){
        if(object.filled == true){
            ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            ctx.fillRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
            ctx.strokeRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
        }
        if(object.filled == false){
            ctx.rect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
            ctx.strokeRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
            }
    }

function fun(){
    renderCanvas();
    renderObject();
}

setInterval(fun, 10);
```

**Here's a screenshot of what my output should be:**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared some canvas code twice. I edited your fiddle and got it working.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6vxd03qq/1/)

The code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width = 500;
canvas.height = 500;

var object = {
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  x: 100,
  y: 50, 
  filled: false  
}

var object1 = {
  height: 50,
  width: 50,
  x: 100,
  y: 50, 
  filled: false  
}


 document.getElementById("moveRight").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.x -= 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("moveLeft").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.x += 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("bigger").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.height += 10;
     object.width += 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("smaller").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.height -= 10;
     object.width -= 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("filled").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.filled = true;
 });
 document.getElementById("empty").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object.filled = false;
 });
  
  
  <!-- 2nd controls -->
  
   document.getElementById("moveRight1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.x -= 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("moveLeft1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.x += 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("bigger1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.height += 10;
     object1.width += 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("smaller1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.height -= 10;
     object1.width -= 10;
 });
 document.getElementById("filled1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.filled = true;
 });
 document.getElementById("empty1").addEventListener("click", function(){
     object1.filled = false;
 });



 function renderCanvas(){
  ctx.fillStyle = "#EEEEEE";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 }

 function renderObject(){
  if(object.filled == true){
   ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
   ctx.fillRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
   ctx.strokeRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
  }
  if(object.filled == false){
   ctx.rect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
   ctx.strokeRect(object.x, object.y, object.width, object.height);
   }
 }
  
  function renderObject1(){
  if(object1.filled == true){
   ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
   ctx.fillRect(object1.x, object1.y, object1.width, object1.height);
   ctx.strokeRect(object1.x, object1.y, object1.width, object1.height);
  }
  if(object.filled == false){
   ctx.rect(object1.x, object1.y, object1.width, object1.height);
   ctx.strokeRect(object1.x, object1.y, object1.width, object1.height);
   }
 }

function fun(){
 renderCanvas();
 renderObject();
  renderObject1();
}
 
setInterval(fun, 10);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<br>
<button id="moveRight"><==</button>
<button id="moveLeft">==></button>
<button id="bigger">Bigger</button>
<button id="smaller">Smaller</button>
<button id="filled">Filled</button>
<button id="empty">Empty</button>

<hr>

<button id="moveRight1"><==</button>
<button id="moveLeft1">==></button>
<button id="bigger1">Bigger</button>
<button id="smaller1">Smaller</button>
<button id="filled1">Filled</button>
<button id="empty1">Empty</button>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This woks perfectly!!

Answer (score 0):

x coordinates for your both objects are same so they are overlapping each other

```
 var object = {
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        x: 100,
        y: 50, 
        filled: false       
} 
var object2 = {
        height: 50,
        width: 50,
        x: 100, //this should be different
        y: 50, 
        filled: false       
    }
```

Another correction is in "renderObject2()" function. there you are using "object" instead of "object2"

Comment: Thanks, I have changed value of x for object2, and corrected renderObject2(), but it is still not working: http://jsfiddle.net/yhhk9meg/ (Although, both rectangles overlap at first, I should be able to move them)

Comment: yes .there are many improvements needed in your code mostly in algorithm.   
1. Render your canvas 
2. Render your first object
3. Render your second object
4. on each button onClick events: 
    a) change coordinates 
    b) delete the earlier rendered rectangle object using or you have to re render the canvas by storing the previous state
    c) render the modified object again.

Comment: ohh i saw the answer posted by claudios now...it is working good